# jquery display image

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to learn jquery. So, first I thought of validating a textbox and check if its length is less than 4 display a stop image adjacent to it.Otherwise, if it is greater than 4 display tick image. SO, i did this

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#' + '<%= tbstreet1.ClientID %>').keyup(isValid);
       function isValid() {
          var street1Length = $('#' + '<%= tbstreet1.ClientID %>').val().length;

          if (street1Length > 4) {
              ShowStop(check);
          }
      };
      function ShowStop(isCheck) {
          if ($('#' + '<%= tbstreet1.ClientID %>').blur()) {
              if (isCheck == true) {
                  $('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" 
                 src="~/tick.gif" /> ');
              }
              else
                  $('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" 
                  src="~/stop.gif" /> ');
          }
      };
      function ActivateSave() {
          $("#MainContent_btn_save").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#MainContent_btn_save").attr("enabled", "");
      };
  });
```

This is my aspx code

```
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="street1" Text="Street1" ></asp:Label> 
   <asp:TextBox ID="tbstreet1" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>  
   <div id="status" runat="server"></div>
```

However, when i run it i dont get the image. Can u please let me know the mistake i've been doing?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but have you considered setting a breakpoint in isValid() and stepping through the code? One way to do it: in Chrome, right-click on the page and choose "Inspect Element." Then use the Scripts tab and select your JavaScript code. This is generally incredibly helpful as you get a hang of JQuery/JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ShowStop(isCheck) {
    if ($('#' + '<%= tbstreet1.ClientID %>').blur()) { // <-- doesn't make any sense, might work if remove...
        if (isCheck == true) {
              $('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" 
             src="~/tick.gif" /> ');
        }
          else
              $('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" 
              src="~/stop.gif" /> ');
        }
};
```

should be,

```
function ShowStop(isCheck) {
        if (isCheck == true) {

              $('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" 
              src="~/tick.gif" /> ');

        } else {

              $('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" 
              src="~/stop.gif" /> ');
        }
};
```

Comment: +1 for "doesn't make sense" but it should still be true and get you to the `if (isCheck == true)`, http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TrvPh/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `check` anywhere so you will get a JavaScript error right here:

```
ShowStop(check);
```

Comment: +1 true! haha nice one... and also check my answer below... :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's not resolving the path to image, so either provide the complete path like this

```
<img align="absmiddle" src="images/stop.gif" />
```

or use `Page.ResolveUrl` to get an absolute path liek this

```
<img align="absmiddle" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/stop.gif") %>' />
```

Comment: my image is directly in the project at root level

Comment: then it should be: <img align="absmiddle" src="stop.gif" />

Comment: tried that. not working, i dont think its the probelm with image. I think it is not going into the diplay image code

Comment: actually, `if ($('#' + '<%= tbstreet1.ClientID %>').blur()) {` line doesn't make any sense there... remove it and I think you're good to go...

Answer (score 0):

`~/` path notation does not work in Javascript:

Instead of

```
$('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" src="~/tick.gif" /> ');
```

Use

```
$('#' + '<%= status.ClientID %>').html('<img align="absmiddle" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/tick.gif") %>" /> ');
```

Comment: tried that. not working, i dont think its the probelm with image. I think it is not going into the diplay image code

Comment: The server won't process `~/` unless it's within a server control.